# Get date when two things appear at the same time (mysql query)

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Is there a sql query that can generate the date when 2 things appear together?
I mean, let's say I have a table consists of bus schedule. Then, I have bus A and B. Bus A will operate on 22 May, 24 May, and 25 May while B operates on 22 May, 24 May and 26 May. I want to get the most recent date that 2 buses appear together which is 24 May.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see those that both buses share:

```
  SELECT t.date
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
   WHERE t.bus IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY t.date
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.bus) = 2
```

To see the most recent date that both buses share:

```
  SELECT t.date
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
   WHERE t.bus IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY t.date
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.bus) = 2
ORDER BY t.date DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table named bus_schedule that contains a bus_name and bus_date field, something like this should work:

```
select bus_schedule_a.bus_date
from bus_schedule bus_schedule_a
inner join bus_schedule bus_schedule_b
on bus_schedule_a.bus_date = bus_schedule_b.bus_date
and bus_schedule_a.bus_name <> bus_schedule_b.bus_name
order by bus_schedule_a.bus_date desc
limit 1
```

Comment: I am so sorry if I did not make it clear. all bus info are store in the same table. So will only have a table named bus_schedule.

Comment: Even though there is only one table, it is possible to join it with itself as I'm doing here.  Actually, a group by approach is probably cleaner though, so I'd recommend taking @omg-ponies approach instead.